# Changing keyboard layout for login screen on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, keyboard-layout, administrator

I have a Mac Mini with Mac OS X Lion.

Basically I am a developer and practiced coding with DVORAK keyboards. So I changed my keyboard layout to DVORAK and I'm working with it. I'm using the `admin` user on my Mac Mini.

When I restart my computer, during login, the layout is changed to QWERTY and it's hard to type the password. It happens only for the admin user though. If I create the another user and set the layout as DVORAK and restart, that user has the DVORAK keyboard for login.

Note: I have a QWERTY keyboard, I'm only changing the layout in the keyboard preferences.

So, to summarize, how can I get the DVORAK keyboard layout for the `admin` login as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normaly you would go to the Systempreferences for Users and Groups, open up the Login Options and there you can select **Show Input menu in login window**. That should give you the possibility to change the keyboard-Layout in the login screen from whats currently selected to your prefered layout.

Have a look at [this Apple-Support document](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4099?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US)

Comment: Yod did it. Thank you so much. I never found that.

Comment: While this answer isn't _wrong_, I doubt it's the answer most folks want.  Most folks will want it fixed *permanently*.  See this [Ask Different Answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/110607/65271) for the "right way" to do this.